# SwiftUI: allow simultaneous gestures with `onDrag` in view?

Tags: swiftui

I am testing out the solution provided by `Asperi` here:

[SwiftUI | Using onDrag and onDrop to reorder Items within one single LazyGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606907/swiftui-using-ondrag-and-ondrop-to-reorder-items-within-one-single-lazygrid)

so,

what I would like to do is to add a `contextMenu` on a cell, and if the user chooses to reorder cells, then would enable the onDrag and onDrop gestures.

I looked into the `simultaneousGesture` but, I am not sure how trigger the contextMenu while the view also has onDrag attached to it.

so I tried something like this:

```
...............

ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
    LazyVGrid(columns: gridItems, spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(model.data) { d in
            GridItemView(d: d)
                .frame(width: side, height: side)
                .overlay(dragging?.id == d.id ? Color.white.opacity(0.8) : Color.clear)
                .contextMenu {
                    Button {
                        editCells.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Label("Edit...", systemImage: "pencil")
                    }

                    // other options .....
                }
                .onDrag {
                    self.dragging = d
                    return NSItemProvider(object: String(d.id) as NSString)
                }
                .disabled(!editCells)
                .onDrop(of: [UTType.text], delegate: DragRelocateDelegate(item: d, listData: $model.data, current: $dragging))
                            .disabled(!editCells)
           }
        }
       .animation(.default, value: model.data)

...............
```

So, the contextMenu never triggers unless I remove the onDrag and onDrop gestures first.

Is there a way to use the contextMenu to "enter" an edit mode to allow drag and drop? Is there a way to make it work while the onDrag and onDrop gestures are installed on the view?

Asperi is right. For the curious as to how I got around doing this I used this conditional View extension:

```
extension View {
    /// Applies the given transform if the given condition evaluates to `true`.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - condition: The condition to evaluate.
    ///   - transform: The transform to apply to the source `View`.
    /// - Returns: Either the original `View` or the modified `View` if the condition is `true`.
    @ViewBuilder func `if`<Content: View>(_ condition: Bool, transform: (Self) -> Content) -> some View {
        if condition {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The both use same gesture (LongPress) for activation, so there is direct conflict. A possible approach is to make onDrag conditional (toggled by some external command).

The `Draggable/canDrag` can be similar as `Droppable/acceptDrop` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61081772/12299030.